If for all $m,n$ the natural numbers $m + n$ and $m^2 + n^2+1$ are painted in the same color, does it follow that all the numbers have the same color?
I was puzzled by an interesting problem. The problem is: all Natural numbers are painted in certain colors. It is known that for any $ m, n \in \mathbb{Z}_+ $, the numbers of the form
$$
m + n, \quad m^2 + n^2 + 1
$$
are painted in a same color. Are all numbers painted in one color?
To prove my hypotosis, I wrote simple program on python, as it confirmed conjecture for large N, I tried searching for math proof.
I tried to prove by contradiction, considering different cases, then $n + m$ is even or odd but didn't succeed. Also tried to proove it by induction,I got stuck and couldn't move forward. Can anyone give me a hint or a solution of this little problem?
P.S. I edit the problem so that it conveyed the correct meaning.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Disclaimer: I tried searching around, but couldn't find a reasonable duplicate, or an abstract duplicate. This solution is novel to me. If this is in violation, please let me know and I will delete this solution.
Hint: Show that $2, 3, 4$ have the same color.

 For each pair of neighbors in the following sequence, find a corresponding $m, n$ to show that they have the same color.
$$ 2, 3, 6, 19, 206, 17, 146, 13, 86, 11, 4.$$

Note: Trying to prove this hint will give you familiarity with how to play around with the sequences, even though it doesn't seem related to the following writeup.
That is because I have reworked and restructured the solution several times to make the logic immediate/obvious, but that stripped away all the ground-up approaches that i used, and hence the steps might seem magical.

Gist of solution: Step 1: Find families of solutions to $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2$, so that $a+b, c+d$ have the same color (as $a^2+b^2+1$).
Step 2: Use this to show that all large enough numbers have the same color.
Step 3: Then, given any number, show that it has the same color as a large enough number.

Observation: For integers $a, b, c, n$, the Fermat 2-square identity gives us:
$$(an-bc)^2 + (bn+ac)^2 = (a^2+b^2)(c^2+n^2) =  (an+bc)^2 + (bn-ac)^2.$$
Corollary, Step 1: For integers $a, b, c$, with $n > \max(\frac{ac}{b}, \frac{bc}{a})$, then $(a+b)n+(a-b)c, (a+b)n - (a-b)c$ have the same color.
Corollary: With $(a, b, c) = (1, 2, 1)$: For $ n \geq 3$, $3n-1, 3n+1$ have the same color.
With $(a, b, c) = (1, 2, 2)$: For $n \geq 5$, $3n-2, 3n+2$ have the same color.
Hence, for $ N \geq 5$, $3N+2, 3N+4, 3N+8, 3N+10, \ldots $ have the same color.
Corollary: With $(a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3)$: For $ n\geq 7$, $3n-3, 3n+3$ have the same color.
Hence, for $  N\geq 6$, $3N, 3N+6, 3N+12, 3N+18, \ldots$ have the same color.
Corollary: With $(a, b, c) = (1, 3, 1)$, $4n-2, 4n+2$ have the same color.
With $n = 3k+1$, then $12n+2$ and $ 12n+6$ have the same color.
Hence, for $N \geq 6$, all $3N+2k$ have the same color.
Corollary, Step 2: Notice that $18+2k$ are the even numbers $\geq 18$. Then for any odd number $n > 18$, it has the same color as $1 + (n-1)^2 + 1  $ which is an even number $\geq 18$. Hence all numbers $\geq 18$ have the same color.
Corollary, Step 3: For any $m \geq 2$, $m$ has the same color as $1^2 + (m-1)^2 + 1 \geq m+1$.
By repeating this, it eventually has the same color as some number $\geq 18$.
Hence all numbers have the same color.

Clearly $1$ can have any colour independent of the others, but I will show that all integers $m \geq 2$ must be painted with the same colour. To this end, we note the identity for positive integers $m$ and $n$ with $m > 2n$,
$$
(2m+n)^2 + (m-2n)^2 = (2m - n)^2 + (m+2n)^2.
$$
This shows that on the one hand,
$$
3m - n \quad \text{and} \quad (2m+n)^2 + (m-2n)^2 + 1
$$
have the same colour, whereas on the other
$$
3m + n \quad \text{and} \quad (2m - n)^2 + (m+2n)^2 + 1
$$
have the same colour. The identity now shows that $3m-n$ and $3m+n$ must have the same colour for all integers $m > 2n$. We apply this to $n = 1, 2, 3$ to find that
$$
3m - 1 \quad \text{and} \quad 3m + 1 \quad \text{(rule 1)}
$$
are painted the same colour as soon as $m \geq 3$,
$$
3m - 2 \quad \text{and} \quad 3m + 2 \quad \text{(rule 2)}
$$
are painted the same colour as soon as $m \geq 5$, and
$$
3m - 3 \quad \text{and} \quad 3m + 3 \quad \text{(rule 3)}
$$
are painted the same colour as soon as $m \geq 7$. Suppose now that for some positive integer $k \geq 7$ we have shown that all numbers from $1$ to $3k$ are painted the same colour. Then rule 1 with $m=k$ shows that $3k+1$ is also painted in the same colour, rule 2 shows that $3k+2$ is also painted in the same colour, and rule 3 shows that $3k+3$ is also painted in the same colour. This would complete the proof by induction.
We have therefore reduced to showing that all numbers from $1$ to $21$ must be painted the same colour. This is just labour and is best checked with some code. From your post I understand that you have already verified this by yourself, so I will not repeat this here.

The remaining maps - adjacent numbers must be of the same colour : $$2\to7:{\mathbf{2},\mathbf{3},\mathbf{6},\mathbf{19},206,\mathbf{17},146,\mathbf{13},86,\mathbf{11},\mathbf{4},\mathbf{9},46,1301,38,\mathbf{7}}$$
$$6\to18:{6,27,630,33,\mathbf{8},51,\mathbf{10},83,5826,99,\mathbf{14},\mathbf{5},\mathbf{18}}$$
$$6\to21:\left{ 6,21\right}$$
$$6\to12:{6,27,426,29,786,39,1446,53,2706,73,\mathbf{12}}$$
$$13\to15:\left{ 13,126,\mathbf{15}\right} \qquad14\to20:\left{ 14,131,\mathbf{16},201,\mathbf{20}\right} $$

FYI If instead you show that all large enough numbers have the same color, then there is no need to check the small cases (which has the same color as a really large number). I've undeleted my solution so you can see how to make that work. I used the same families as you, and then another to "cross-pollinate" them.
